# make a query, get results make query again

Tags: mysql

i want to execute these queries in a single statement  :- How TO ??

```
SELECT count(id) as levela FROM `member` where parent_id in (SELECT id FROM `member` where parent_id in (SELECT id FROM `member` where parent_id = 2 )) 

SELECT count(id) as levelb FROM `member` where parent_id in (SELECT id FROM `member` where parent_id = 2)

SELECT count(id) as levelb FROM `member` where parent_id =  2
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: @JurijJazdanov how to do this????????????????????????/

Comment: you want to get the total count from all 3 queries?

Comment: @JurijJazdanov yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use instead 'where', 'where in' - where in allows You to serach in array. 
for example :

```
Select id from member where parent_id IN (here array ($y) )
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use this

```
SELECT id FROM member where parent_id IN (x, y, z)
```

If with a difficult you can use sub query like this:

```
SELECT id FROM member where parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM list_parent_id WHERE "condition you want to find" )
```

Hope this help =)

Comment: you can use UNION statement, hope this can help you