# get required result in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

i have a sql database having two columns
1. id and 2. parent_id

i want to select all ids where parent_id=1 [let the results saved in X array] then,
select all the ids where parent_id in X[] [let the results saved in Y array] then... do the same upto 7 levels at last i want to sum all levels and get that sum in a variable name "number"

what i tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(id) as leadersearch FROM `$database`.`$mem` where parent_id = ".$parent[id];
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$lv1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

then again

```
$sql = "SELECT count(id) as leadersearch FROM `$database`.`$mem` where parent_id in ($lv1)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$lv2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

and so on.... it may give me required result but it is too much code...
i want to the same by using a loop or something else... to shorten the code.

Comment: *"but it is too much code"* - Define "too much code"; I don't see much code here to start with.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i mean i have to paste the same three lines 7 times but i want to do it with a loop

Comment: Ddin't you already ask something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/q/46215054/

Comment: @RajanSinghSood. . you should not take SO for granted if you keep posting questions like this, you should consider some tutorial first. After that if you still have some issues, come to SO

Comment: yes but it answered me in getting use (where in) it helped me but i want to do it with a loop

Comment: @RajanSinghSood consider closing the question then by accepting the answer given. Otherwise, it'll either be a repost or people think it's still unsolved; so is the other one unsolved?

Comment: @hanishsingla i had seen some tutorials but i want to do it with a loop... the tutorial helped in how to do it with full code... but it didnt helped if i have to do the same thing with a loop

Answer (score 0):

Your first query gets count(id) and then second query uses it to get results. It seems you have many flaws in your requirement to begin with.

However, for your question you can use sub-query like following

```
$sql = "SELECT count(id) as leadersearch 
 FROM `$database`.`$mem` 
 WHERE parent_id in (
       SELECT id FROM `$database`.`$mem` where parent_id = ".$parent['id']."
  )";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$lv2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

If you have many level nesting and you want to search records like this then you can consider functions:

```
function getLeader($parent_id){
    $results = [];
    $sql = "SELECT id as leadersearch FROM `$database`.`$mem` where parent_id in (".$parent_id.")";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    foreach($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $results[] = $row['id'];
    }

    return $results;
}

$leaders = [];
$ids = getLeader($parent['id']);
foreach($ids as $id){
    $leaders[$id] = getLeader($id);
}
```

Comment: i said i have to do this upto 7 levels means first result then use it to get second result, then use second result to get third result then use third result to get fourth result. what i need to go on  upto seventh result... so iwant to do it with a loop

Comment: @RajanSinghSood. . I have updated my answer . .does that solves what issue you facing?

Comment: it worked upto 2 levels but when i tried to use the foreach loop with $leaders['$id'] it says

Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\delta\admin\process\test.php on line 32

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\delta\admin\process\test.php on line 8

Comment: You must be returning array instead of  `$results[] = $row['id'];`